# Algorithms to recognize names with different formats in texts

Tags: algorithm, string, search, nlp

I need to develop an application that will index several texts and I need to search for people’s names inside these texts. The problem is that, while a person’s full name name is “Gregory Jackson Junior”, inside the text, the name might me written as:

- Greg Jackson Jr
- Gegory Jackson Jr
- Gregory Jackson
- Gregory J. Junior 
  I plan to index the texts on a nightly bases and build a database index to speed up the search. I would like recommendation for good books and/or good articles on the subject.
  Thanks

Comment: You question is incorrectly phrased. The examples do not indicate misspelling but change in the form of writing a full name. And, I am curious, would your search expect to match on words like 'son' with reference to the example?

Comment: Actually, one of the names might me misspelled as well. I don't need synonym matches like junior and son.
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find anything to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Check these related questions.

[Algorithm to find articles with similar text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246961/algorithm-to-find-similar-text)

[How to search for a person's name in a text? (heuristic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338661/how-to-search-for-a-persons-name-in-a-text-heuristic)

Comment: Thanks for the references. I did check them out prior to posting the question. The first one was focused on articles and real-time search. And the second article, the best answers were refering to a particular database engine, but had little algorithm content.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is incorrectly phrased. The examples do not indicate misspelling but change in the form of writing a full name.

And,

- would your search expect to match on words like **son** with reference to the example?
- would it expect to [match **bob** when looking for a name called **Robert**](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/62443-robert-bob-formation-names-english.html)?

  - Are you looking for things like [this](http://www.geocities.com/edgarbook/names/other/nicknames.html) and [this](http://www.spiritus-temporis.com/nickname/nicknames-for-people.html)?

Ok, reading your comment suggests you do not want to venture into that.

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect phrasing. No need for synonym or nicknames.

Answer (score 1):

For the record. Use a Bayesian filter. You may use mechanical truck for initializing your algorithm.